# HTML Element alignment using Jquery

Tags: alignment, html-table

I have a table with three columns, the first column takes an image, the second takes a heading label and third is very small and is empty.
The Heading label in second column is being centered to the center of the column but what I want is to center it in the middle of the screen at the same height it is present at. I used jquery window width but couldn't attain the result required. The heading label is made up of two labels.
please help....!

Comment: Do you have a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you use table.Insted of table use divs.Here i paste the code for that

you want to align the center of `<div id="myDiv"></div>` to the center of `<span id="mySpan"></span>` write

```
 $("#myDiv").align({left:{my:0.5,at:0.5, selector:'#mySpan'}, top:{my:0.5,at:0.5, selector:'#mySpan'}});
```

Comment: No, the page was designed around 4 years ago and it is a standard template of current project, even though I wish to change it to div's, my team would n't happy. Above all its the master page so they don't want it to be edited much. Is it possible to take the length of each label add them together and subtract the half length from centre of the screen to position it exactly in the mid of screen. I have tried the above but I am unable to trap the centre of the screen or browser window. If it is not possible please provide an explanation, so that I could know why would it work or not work.